# How do split this code so that I can call it in the main method and return the statement from a method in a different file?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

I need to split this code in a way where I would be calling it from the main and doing the sorting in another method in a different file.

**This is what I have in the main:**

```
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //array of 10 numbers
            double numbers[] = new double[]{1.9, 2.5, 3.7, 2, 1.5, 6, 3 , 4 , 5, 2};

            //assign first element of an array to largest and smallest
            double smallest = numbers[0];
            double largetst = numbers[0];

            for(int i=1; i< numbers.length; i++)
            {
                    if(numbers[i] < smallest)
                            smallest = numbers[i];

            }
            System.out.println("The minimum number is: " + smallest);
    }

    }
```

**This is the other method:**

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class Chapter8 {
    public static void chap8method(){}
    public static double[][] sortRows(double[][] m) {
    Chapter8.chap8method();
    double[][] result = Chapter8.sortRows(m);
     }
    }
```

Comment: i'm not sure your question is clear enough can you edit and add comments on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think this is an assignment for learning sorting algorithms. If so search for java code samples (bubble sort, etc) Otherwise you can use a list and java.util.Collections.sort method which java already has.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with the main method.

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       //if your sort method is static in another class
Sort.sortRows(

//if your method is non static than create an object of that class
Sort obj = new Sort();
obj.sortRows
    }
}
```

Your another class:

Sort.java

```
public class Sort{

 public static double sortRows(double[][] m) {
//your sorting logic here

    }
}
```